# Running docker in docker in AWS Fargate

Tags: linux, docker, aws

I am thinking of running docker in docker using [this](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/).
Can I run it in AWS Fargate task? It doesn't have underlying host so was not sure that would work or not.